# get data from documents

Tags: php, javascript, html, document, converters

I want to make a web app that can get the values from a commonly used file type (such as xsl or ppt) to allow me to convert it into a custom format (like Google Drive). With an xsl (excel document) file, for example, I want to be able to get the value for each cell. I would be fine getting html for a file (like getting the html code that would display a word document) because values can be extracted out of that. I would like to be able to do it on the client side, but I am okay with using it on the server side with PHP.

Comment: need to do this on server, no access to these files with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to import the file as XML. PHP has great support for [XML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) and could make short work of this. If you can get the files uploaded as [Open Doc Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) you can parse just about any of the types you listed (XLS, PPT, DOC, etc).

Comment: This is great! I am fine with it being on the server, but I would prefer it on the client. Do you think it would be possible for me to do this E4X (ECMAScript for XML)?

Comment: Okay, I found out how to do this, all on the client: unzip the odf file using a javascript unzipping utility. The files can then be processed with E4X.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty easy way to get data out of an excel sheet online is to use a [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/). The process would be a lot to explain here, but with a bit of google searching, you can find all your answers.

As for a PPT, I can't think of an easy way.

As for documents (i.e. pdf, doc, docx), you can use Google Apps Script as well.

Although, if you're making your own tool for this, you may want to just research how the data is stored in the file and work from there.